# 'Upload' function not working for Jupyter Notebook in ssh mode on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04, jupyter-irkernel

I am new to using Jupyter, but am well versed with R. My new role requires me to use R-Kernel inside a jupyter notebook via ssh to share common data and save space. However, I am unable to upload any files from my local machine for some reason - although the permissions check out. There is no error - the entire computer just hangs the moment I click 'Upload'!! Has anybody ever faced this issue?

I am using Jupyter 3.1.18 via ssh on Ubuntu 18.04.
I don't have jupyter installed on my local machine.

Comment: Are you able to upload files to other websites using the same browser?

Comment: Also, you probably use Jupyter**Lab** - based on the version number (which is not the latest version I will note).

Comment: Have you tried uploading files by dragging them into the file browser area on the left from your system file browser?

Comment: So of course the simple 'drag and drop' worked! I was using port forwarding and wanted to upload a file from my local machine 'A' via a server at 'B' to a host at 'C'....and tried scp but was stuck with identifying the IP at 'C'. I tried drag and drop today and it worked....the 'Upload' function is still not working though!